# Powershell to convert registry to XML for GPO assignment

Tags: xml, windows, powershell, registry, gpo

To have the taskbar pinned applications customized via a GPO on a domain I have to have an XML version of a registry export.  (There is not a windows 10 Taskbar Pinned apps setting so it has to be done via reg setting)

I have looked for registry-to-XML converters so that I can have an XML file for my GPO, but I have not found a functioning one.

Does anyone have a link to a functioning powersheel script, or can identify what is wrong with these?

The script from this page:
https://4sysops.com/archives/convert-reg-to-xml-to-import-registry-key-into-group-policy-preferences/

https://4sysops.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/RegToXML.zip

gets me this error:

```
New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "Could not find file 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\test1.reg'."
At C:\RegToXML.ps1:43 char:7
+   $sr=New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($regPath)
+       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\RegToXML.ps1:53 char:5
+     $line = $sr.ReadLine()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

The script from here:
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Registry-To-GroupPolicyPref-9feae9a3

Results in this error:

```
C:\Convert-RegToGppXml.ps1 : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'SourcePath'. Cannot convert the
".\test1.reg" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.ValidateNotNullOrEmptyAttribute".
At line:1 char:39
+ .\Convert-RegToGppXml.ps1 -SourcePath .\test1.reg -ResultPath .\test1 ...
+                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Convert-RegToGppXml.ps1], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationExcept
   ion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Convert-RegToGppXml.ps1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use that script from MS-Gallery ( Convert-RegToGppXml.ps1 ) then you should use the complete Sourcepath (e.g. C:\users\xyz\script.reg). Dont use quotation marks in path!